# Using backend for domain layer in clean architecture for android / web

Tags: android, google-app-engine, web, google-cloud-platform, clean-architecture

In every article I have read about clean architecture in Android, I see the domain layer's classes are in the android project. But, if this layer are completely independant from outer layers, is it correct to move this layer to any backend service (google app engine, for example) if the project had android and web interfaces?
I mean, one presentation layer for android and one presentation layer for web (javascript, etc.), but both using the same domain layer.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your domain layer (I assume you mean the data models) is subject to the language it's being written for. For example, if you frontend is Android/Java and your backend is in Python, you can't share a domain layer. Generally, I end up writing the models to mimic what the backend is providing unless the backend I'm working with has a Client SDK where all the models are already developed for me, and usable in the java land

Comment: @rosenthal Thank you!